# How to link to each nested routes in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I've got an ember app where my routing looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('works', {path: '/works'}, function(){
    this.route('work', {path:':work_id'})
  });
});
```

I want to be able to link each of my work in my index template, for my naviguation. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='application'>
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">
      <div class="item-container">
        {{#link-to 'works' tagName='div' classNames="navItem work" }}
        <p>Works</p>
        {{/link-to}}
        <ul>
          {{#link-to 'work' works work}}{{work.title}}{{/link-to}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    {{outlet}}
  </main>
</script>
```

If you need more info just let me know.

Comment: Please describe what you expect to happen and what happened instead. IE Clarify "It didn't work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index route definitions should look like this (assuming you are using Ember Data):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('work');
  }
});
```

Then in your `index` template go through `{{each}}` of the `App.Work` records and link to the `works.work` route:

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{#link-to 'works.work' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: My route looks exactly that way, but i want to do this in my index page not works or work page. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Now let say i want to add a team route with a nested route of all the members, and i also want to loop trough all the members in my index template?

Comment: @DrEvowl please open a new question for loading multiple models in a route, or search in stackoverflow; there must be something related. Its hard to answer in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

When linking to a route, you do resource.route

```
{{#link-to 'works.work' work}}{{work.title}}{{/link-to}}
```

In this case I'm assuming work is a property that is a model, if not, you'll need to show your router.